# http.host filter for tshark capturing

Tags: wireshark

I would like to capture traffic to a specific domain name. I tried the following wireshark filter

```
http.host == 'example.com'
```

It works, but after a few hours the temp data gets very large, so I tried to use tshark & capture filters to only capture and save the traffic that is going to example.com

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "Host example.com" -w "/tmp/d.pcap"
```

However, this is capturing everything.

Is there anyway I can capture only the traffic going to a specific domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Capture filters are case sensitive:

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "host example.com" -w "/tmp/d.pcap"
```

Comment: didnt make any diffrence ... still all packets are captured and saved to disk

Comment: Please remember that the packet filter `http.host` is not the same as the capture filter `host`.  The capture filter will resolve the DNS name to an IP and capture any traffic to/from that IP.

Comment: i want to save only packets that contain the http header (host: example.com) is there any filter for this ?